# Show different title on category page

Tags: categories, title, seo

In my category pages, the title of the category is shown as the title of the page. I want to have a different title, for SEO purposes. How can this be done?

Say my category is `mystery books` I want the search engine to see a title like  "The Best Mystery Books" instead of "mystery books" that it sees now. I don't care if this title is also shown on the actual page or not.

This is the code I use for the title of category pages:

```
<header class="page-header">
                    <h1 itemprop="headline" class="page-title">
                        <?php if ( is_category() ) {
                        single_cat_title( '', true );
                        } ?>
                    </h1><!-- .page-title -->
</header><!-- .page-header -->
```

The "problem" seems to be that WP automatically generates `<title>` tags from the `<header> <h1>` of the page.
Any ideas?

Maybe I need a function that checks if it is a `category` and puts the relevant `<title>` in the `<head>` of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change this in, most likely, your `header.php` file in your themes root. I would suggest that you use something like [YoastSEO Plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/) which will give you granular manipulation of your sites `<title>` and `<meta>` tags. If this is not an option, you would have to dive into the `header.php` template and update it there.

For example:

```
<?php if( is_category( 'my-category-slug' ) ) : ?>
    <title><?php _e( 'The Best Mystery Books' ) ; ?></title>
<?php else : ?>
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure to check that the slug (`'my-category-slug'`) matches your `mystery book` slug. You can see more about the arguments that can be passed to `is_category()` for more relevant matching.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it would work the same without the `else`.

Comment: if your not on `is_category( 'my-category-slug' )` it would output nothing without the `else`, unless your using a plugin that does this.

Comment: 'wp_title()' does this automatically already before I added the code, right? I don't see the point to add it.